# Want to build project with commandline mvn but have to use Maven update in eclipse first

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm working with multiple projects in Eclipse. because I want to automate the building I want to script the building process.

Unfortunately I cannot do the same actions on the commandline as in Eclipse.

So a common problem is that when a new function from a referenced project is used, I cannot build the project on the commandline with mvn. I use the command:
mvn clean install -U

But this command will give a build failure until I do a Eclipse Maven Update from the eclipse GUI. After that I can build the project again.

I also tried all the other commands I came across Stackoverflow:
mvn eclipse:eclipse
mvn dependency:resolve

So I just want to that Maven Update command in eclipse from the commandline so I can build from the commandline. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be awesome.

Thx in advance

---

Update for more clarification:
The project structure is:
Rest-service, Framework-service, Framework-model

Framework-model is referenced in the pom file by Framework-service and Framework-service is referenced by Rest-service. The other projects are not relevant to the problem.

When a function is added to Framework-model and used in Rest-service it gives an compilation error in eclipse and when I build with mvn clean install -U, although Maven install in eclipse is succesful but I think it is still using the old compiled code. After a Maven Update command in eclipse the compilation error is gone. And mvn clean install -U from the commandline also works.

How could I do a Maven Update command in the commandline? If mvn clean install -U should also do a Maven Update command, what settings should I check?

Another update: So this weekend I tried different things and running mvn compile before the mvn clean install -U command gives a different output. And finds the new function. But as I read maven, I thought install should also do the previous steps. How is this possible?

Comment: Executing Maven from command line is independent of Eclipse. So, you shouldn't have to perform Eclipse Maven Update before building it from Command Line. I believe there is some issue with your project hierarchy setup. You probably have dependent projects but don't aggregate them in a parent POM.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's Maven plugin uses the maven version configured in Preferences/Maven/User settings. If you have a different version of maven in your Eclipse's settings than the one on your PATH variable, you could have different outputs. Maybe try and check that.